# Chromium process 16 exabytes of virtual memory?

Tags: chromium, ram

I am running Chromium and was looking in the task manager, and noticed that a "chro" process (which I believe is related to Chromium) is occasionally jumping from 1.9GB of memory to 16,777,216TB, or 16 Exabytes. This seems a little large. I know virtual memory isn't "real", but wondering if anyone had some insight as to why this might be happening. Could this be an issue with the task manager doing a calculation incorrectly?

[image: exabytes of fun]

While I would love to have 16EB of memory, my computer really only has 16GB.

**Edit:**
It seems this is a task manager issue and not a Chromium issue, per this screenshot I just took.

[image]

Comment: This must be a chromium bug. What other answer do you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more digging, have confirmed this is a known bug with LXTask version < 0.1.5. Seems this is fixed in new versions but does not ship with 14.04.

http://sourceforge.net/p/lxde/bugs/467/